# Launching a program with Voce

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I've compiled with success my first program with the Voce library but when I start the program, it stops right after. I can't say any word and it stops

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <voce.h>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    voce::init("voce/lib", false, true, "voce/lib/grams", "digits");

    while (voce::getRecognizerQueueSize() > 0)
    {
        std::string s = voce::popRecognizedString();
        std::cout << "You said: " << s << std::endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

I took this code on : http://voce.sourceforge.net/

Thank you for your help

Comment: it stops right after... what? init? while (...)? system("PAUSE");?

Comment: So inside the while? Or is it just pausing? Did you debugged it? Is the while (...) executed?

Comment: Try putting that while loop inside another while loop, and have an exit digit (like when you say 9 or some number it will exit the program), and get rid of the system pause. When the program first runs the queue size is not greater than zero yet.

Comment: I did what you said and it returns 9. I think the program doesn't enter the while loop

Comment: Did you do something like `while(s.find("zero") == std::string::npos){//your while loop here}`? So as long as you don't say "zero" it won't be found in the string and the program will keep looking for digits that you say and outputting them.

Comment: yes but it continues to finish with exit digit 0. I think it doesn't enter the while loop

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're doing wrong. Put some output (debug) statements so you can "see" what's happening. Like one after init that says "initialized" and then maybe one after the while loop, like "entering system pause". Or just put your while loop in an infinite while so that it can't exit, and see if you get any voice recognition. I think "digits" mean that it will only recognize spoken numerical digits right? And those words should be in the grammar file.

Comment: I already tried to put an infinite while loop but it doesn't work

Comment: I will maybe try to re-install Voce and to relink the library

Comment: Voce is not a reasonable thing to use. It is painful wrapper around Java API which itself is wrapped in C. I'd better use other speech APIs, for example, Microsoft SAPI or CMUSphinx